# Unable to locate correct java.util

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a small program. During compilation, it tries to look at wrong path for java util libs. Below is the compilation output

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked adssim/util/XMLParser.java
adssim/util/XMLParser.java:3: error: cannot access util
import java.util.Vector;
           ^
  bad source file: ./java/util.java
    file does not contain class java.util
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

File loation

```
/apps/oasis/adarsh/adssim/util>ls -lrt XMLParser.java
-rwxrwxrwx   1 oasis    oasis       1258 Apr  8 15:49 XMLParser.java
```

Classpath

```
/apps/oasis/adarsh/adssim/util>echo $CLASSPATH
:/apps/oasis/java/classes12.jar:/apps/oasis/java/ifxjdbc.jar:/apps/oasis/java/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/apps/oasis/java/commons-io-2.5.jar:/apps/oasis/adarsh/adssim:/apps/oasis/adarsh/adssim/util:/apps/oasis/adarsh/adssim/util/crypto:/apps/oasis/adarsh/adssim/channel:/apps/oasis/adarsh
```

File Source

```
package adssim.util;

import java.util.Vector;

public class XMLParser
{
        public static Vector getXMLTagValue(String xml, String section) throws Exception
        {
                String xmlString = new String(xml);
                Vector v = new Vector();
```

What am i doing wrong guys ?

Comment: This sounds extremely weird, almost as the same magnitude as this: https://xkcd.com/1084/ I'm sorry, but I can only give you the advice the shut down your computer and wait for the singularity. ;)

Comment: Joke aside, it seems very strange. The only advice I can think of is to clear the `CLASSPATH` variable and try again. It might be something weird there that causes the problem. If the problem goes away you can try to add back the class path entries one after the other until you find the culprit.

Comment: Ok @Lii . Let me try

Comment: Is there a file on your disk that is actually called `util.java` in a directory called `java`? Maybe you have created such a file by mistake? The message `bad source file: ./java/util.java` makes it sound like that.

Comment: YES !!!! I can see one file. Let me rename and five a try ...

Comment: Compiled perfectly :)

Comment: Nice! :) I wonder what you might have done to accidentally create it... I'll turn my comment into an answer.

Comment: It was a file created long back. since its a development region, we just write code just anywhere : ), and i had no clue of such a file unless you mentioned and i did a search from base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a file on your disk that is actually called `util.java` in a directory called `java`? Maybe you have created such a file by mistake?

This part of the error message makes it sound like that:

> bad source file: `./java/util.java`